# c# DES ECB mode длина зашифрованного блока больше 64 bit

Tags: c#, криптография

длина блока на входе 64 bit.

```
byte[] testArray = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

алгоритм для кодирования DES ECB

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] bytesForEncyption)
    {
        DES desAlg = DES.Create();
        desAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        desAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        desAlg.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("11223344");
        desAlg.BlockSize = 64;
        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using(CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, desAlg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesForEncyption, 0, bytesForEncyption.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

На выходе получаю 128 bit зашифрованных данных.
Хотя должно быть 64 bit

в чём ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё верно, вы установили `desAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7`, а он должен дополнить сообщение до полного блока. Так как предыдущий блок уже полностью занят, то идет дополнение новым блоком. Вы можете выставить `desAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None`, тогда получите 8 байт на выходе.

Comment: а разве у DES размер полного блока 128 bit?

Comment: @Deim 64, получается 2 блока в итоге